# How to get list of file from Azure blob using Spark/Scala?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage

How to get list of file from Azure blob storage in Spark and Scala.

I am not getting any idea to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Spark you used is either on Azure or on local. So they are two cases, but similar.

1. For Spark running on local, there is an offical [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2016/07/13/accessing-azure-storage-blobs-from-spark-1-6-that-is-running-locally/) which introduces how to access Azure Blob Storage from Spark. The key is that you need to configure Azure Storage account as HDFS-compatible storage in `core-site.xml` file and add two jars `hadoop-azure` & `azure-storage` to your classpath for accessing HDFS via the protocol `wasb[s]`. You can refer to the offical [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage) to know HDFS-compatible storage with `wasb`, and the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2013/04/25/access-azure-blob-stores-from-hdinsight/) about configuration for HDInsight more details.
2. For Spark running on Azure, the difference is just only access HDFS with `wasb`, the other preparations has been done by Azure when creating HDInsight cluster with Spark.

The method for listing files is [`listFiles`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@listFiles():Seq[String]) or [`wholeTextFiles`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@wholeTextFiles(path:String,minPartitions:Int):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,String)]) of `SparkContext`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using databricks, try the below

dbutils.fs.ls(“blob_storage_location”)