# To get the list of filename stored in azure data lake through scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-lake, databricks

I need a list of files from azure data lake store at databricks notebook.
I have a script of scala but i think it is only access the files from local filesystem.

```
val path = "adl://datalakename.azuredatalakestore.net"
import java.io._

def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[String] = {
   val file = new File(dir)
   file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
      .filter(_.getName.endsWith(".dat"))
      .map(_.getPath).toList
}
getListOfFiles(path + "/folder/subfolder/")
```

but it can't work and throw an exception error as like - java.lang.NullPointerException
Any suggestion or help in python/scala.

Comment: You can't use standard IO API to access distributed Azure File System. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474304/how-to-get-list-of-file-from-azure-blob-using-spark-scala

Comment: yes, i got it but still i don't know which library or any method is used to access the azure filesystem on my notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working on Azure Databricks you could just use dbutils:

```
// Access Azure Data Lake Store
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", "xxx)
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential", "xxx")
spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url", "https://login.windows.net/xxx/oauth2/token")

val path="adl://datalakename.azuredatalakestore.net"
val filelist=dbutils.fs.ls(path)
print(filelist)
```

For more info just type:
    dbutils.fs.help()

Comment: Do you know the import for dbutils.fs? I'm unable to make this work with `import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils`

Comment: if you are working in databricks you need nothing to import it is part of the runtime

Comment: to convert the files to List                                                                                              val files:List[String] = dbutils.fs.ls(path).map(_.path).toList